NGINX proxy manager with blue/green deployment approach
I am trying to implement a zero downtime deployment approach using the blue/green approach.
We manage our nginx config through the Nginx proxy manager (link), and this where I am stuck.
What I have learnt is that my nginx config needs to incorporate some of the below>
upstream app_upstream {
  server prod_master_blue:3000;
  # server prod_master_green:3000;   
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_upstream;
  }
}

But I do struggle in terms of how to achieve this along with having the proxy manager configuring our config files.
I can for example not replace our current proxy host with a zero port and the call url app_upstream.
I wonder if somebody has tried this before and figured a way to do this.
